How to start a Spring Batch JAR programmatically
I have a Spring Batch application which has a JAR file in the target folder: "listOfTickers-1.0.0.jar".
Now, I want to launch this JAR from another Java application. How can I launch this JAR programmatically?

This is an unusual request; you usually call the methods you want to execute.  If that's an executable jar, then it has a class with a method of public static void main in it; can you not just call that?  If not, Java has support for running system commands.  You could execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ....").  However, this will be a nightmare; import and call the behavior directly.
